# Android - TextViews not showing up in ListView

Tags: java, android, database, listview, android-fragments

I'm having an issue to where none of my TextViews are showing up in the ListView. I'm not sure whether it is an issue with the layout or the java class itself. There are two images here, one of the application running after data had been entered into the database and one of what it is supposed to look like.

Layout for each row of data in ListView

[image]

Fragment for the ListView (Delete Button appears but not the TextViews)

[image]

row_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="123dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/resultTeamNumber"
        android:text="Here Number"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textPortcullis"
        android:text="Portcullis:"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textChevalFrise"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/resultPortcullis"
        android:text="Yes/No"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/resultTeamNumber"
        android:layout_marginLeft="110dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textChevalFrise"
        android:text="Cheval de Frise:"
        android:layout_below="@+id/resultPortcullis"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:singleLine="false" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/resultChevalFrise"
        android:text="Yes/No"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/resultPortcullis"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/resultPortcullis" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textMoat"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textChevalFrise"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:text="Moat:" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/resultMoat"
        android:text="Yes/No"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/resultChevalFrise"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/resultChevalFrise" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textRamparts"
        android:text="Ramparts:"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textMoat"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/resultRamparts"
        android:text="Yes/No"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textDrawbridge"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/resultMoat" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textDrawbridge"
        android:text="Drawbridge:"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textRamparts"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/resultDrawbridge"
        android:text="Yes/No"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/resultRamparts"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/resultRamparts" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textSallyPort"
        android:text="Sally Port:"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textDrawbridge"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/resultSallyPort"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/resultDrawbridge"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/resultDrawbridge"
        android:text="Yes/No" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textRockWall"
        android:text="Rock Wall:"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/resultPortcullis"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/resultPortcullis"
        android:layout_marginStart="34dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/resultRockWall"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="Yes/No"
        android:layout_marginStart="46dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/resultRockTerrain"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textRockTerrain" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textRockTerrain"
        android:text="Rock Terrain:"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textRockWall"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textRockWall" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/resultRockTerrain"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="Yes/No"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textRockTerrain"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/resultRockWall" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textLowBar"
        android:text="Low Bar:"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:layout_above="@+id/resultRamparts"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textRockTerrain" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/resultLowBar"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="Yes/No"
        android:layout_below="@+id/resultRockTerrain"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/resultRockTerrain" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="Delete"
        android:id="@+id/buttonDelete"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textLowBar"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textLowBar"
        android:layout_above="@+id/resultSallyPort" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

ScoutFragment.java

```
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class ScoutFragment extends Fragment {

    FloatingActionButton addDataScout;
    ListView eListScoutInfo;
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
    Cursor cursor;
    ListScoutInfoAdapter listScoutInfoAdapter;

    public ScoutFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    } //End of ScoutFragment

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scout, null, false);
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        eListScoutInfo = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listScoutInfo);
        listScoutInfoAdapter = new ListScoutInfoAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row_layout);
        eListScoutInfo.setAdapter(listScoutInfoAdapter);
        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        sqLiteDatabase = databaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        cursor = databaseHelper.getInformation(sqLiteDatabase);

        //Checks if information is available in cursor
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                //Declare all strings
                String teamNumber, portcullis, chevalFrise, moat, ramparts, drawbridge, sallyPort, rockWall, rockTerrain, lowBar;

                //Get strings from cursor
                teamNumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseContract.NewDataInfo.COL_NUMBER));
                portcullis =  cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseContract.NewDataInfo.COL_PORTCULLIS));
                chevalFrise = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseContract.NewDataInfo.COL_CHEVAL_FRISE));
                moat = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseContract.NewDataInfo.COL_MOAT));
                ramparts = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseContract.NewDataInfo.COL_RAMPARTS));
                drawbridge = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseContract.NewDataInfo.COL_DRAWBRIDGE));
                sallyPort = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseContract.NewDataInfo.COL_SALLY_PORT));
                rockWall = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseContract.NewDataInfo.COL_ROCK_WALL));
                rockTerrain = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseContract.NewDataInfo.COL_ROCK_TERRAIN));
                lowBar = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseContract.NewDataInfo.COL_LOW_BAR));

                //Get methods from DatabaseProvider
                DatabaseProvider databaseProvider = new DatabaseProvider(teamNumber, portcullis, chevalFrise, moat, ramparts,
                        drawbridge, sallyPort, rockWall, rockTerrain, lowBar);

                //Pass objects to add method
                listScoutInfoAdapter.add(databaseProvider);
                listScoutInfoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        } //End of if statement

        //Setups Floating Action Button
        addDataScout = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fab);
        addDataScout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AddScoutDataFragment fragment = new AddScoutDataFragment();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_left, R.anim.enter_from_left, R.anim.exit_to_right);
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            } //End of onClick
        }); //End of setOnClickListener
        return view;
    } //End of onCreateView
} //End of class
```

I don't believe the issue is with database showing the data because some of the TextViews in the ListView don't even use the data from inside the database.

Comment: change your Theme or set black TextColor.

Comment: There's no need to delete and repost your question. Editing it will bump it to the top of the active queue.

Comment: It works, another issue now though is that my data for drawbridge doesn't pop up, probably the database issue, I'll look into it, thanks

Comment: Didn't realize, thanks Mike

Comment: you have a theme issue

Comment: you are not seeing text becoz text color is white

Comment: I am working on a simialr problem and had same issue with you. While explicitly setting color to black didn't help, I experimented with a few things. At the end, I kept only the following: `android:id`, `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height`, `android:textSize` and `android:visibility` and deleted all other attributes, and the text showed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your row_layout.xml file textview in set textcolor:

```
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="123dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/resultTeamNumber"
    android:text="Here Number"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" 
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
```

/>

Comment: this approach is not better since he has to change textcolor in every textview

Answer (score 1):

It is theme issue on your end,probably textcolor set to white in your theme change these

```
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>
```

change it to black

Answer (score 1):

set your adapter upon listview in the last..............

[image]